# MX Linux に /var/log/wtmp が何故か無い理由を知りたい

Tags: linux

### 質問

Linuxの初学者で、最近`last`コマンドについて勉強し試してみたところ、下記のように出力され`/var/log/wtmp`が自分のPCに存在しないことが分かりました。
理由と対処法を知りたいです。

```sh
$ last
last: cannot open /var/log/wtmp: そのようなファイルやディレクトリはありません
```

### 環境

- OS: MX Linux

Answer (score 4, accepted):

lastコマンド等でログイン記録を確認するのは、Linux が伝統的にはマルチユーザーで利用される事が多いからですが、
一方でOSがインストールされたPCにログインするのは1人しかいないパーソナルな用途での使い方も広まっているため、
MX Linux のデフォルトでは該当のファイルが存在しないようです。

last コマンドでログイン記録を確認できるようにするには、単にログファイルを作成するだけです。

参考
https://forum.mxlinux.org/viewtopic.php?t=45848

```
$ touch /var/log/btmp
$ touch /var/log/wtmp
```

Answer (score 4):

lastコマンドのマニュアル(man pages) 読むとこの様に書かれてるはずです

```
$ man last
```

> そのファイルが作成されて以来ログインした (そして、ログアウトした) すべてのユーザのリストを表示する。

参考 (linuxjm.osdn.jp)
[LAST, LASTB](https://linuxjm.osdn.jp/html/util-linux/man1/last.1.html)

つまり(どこかの時点で)**作成しない限り**, いつまで経っても使えない・記録されない, ということ
(最初から用意されてるディストリビューションが多いが, その辺りは用意する側の方針で異なる)

---

対処方法: ファイル作ってください
(通常のものと異常用と)

```sh
$ sudo touch /var/log/wtmp
$ sudo touch /var/log/btmp
```

参考 (MX Linux Forum)
https://forum.mxlinux.org/viewtopic.php?p=496200#p496200

---

(追記)
man last の説明だけでは不足かもしれないのて, 「作成しない限り使えない」辺りを文中に追記